# Algorand: What is store integer count 7 exceeds schema integer count 6?

Tags: algorand, pyteal

I couldn't understand what is the following error in Algorand. I couldn't find a document for this either.

```
AlgodHTTPError: TransactionPool.Remember: transaction AFARFFGAZE7IXA2ZVPGCNTJVTUHX2IZKVSKY7US24JANRK7LZRXA: logic eval error: store integer count 7 exceeds schema integer count 6. Details: pc=542, opcodes=global CurrentApplicationAddress
callsub label13
app_global_put
```

Thats the call that I am trying to invoke:

```
   on_init = Seq(
        Assert(
            And(
                Txn.sender() == Global.creator_address(),
            )
        ), 
        App.globalPut(GlobalState.Variables.asset_id, create_asset(Global.current_application_address())),
        Approve(),
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some tests I just discovered that Global Variables only had 6 integer positions.

You can modify this by increasing the number of variables:

```
global_schema = transaction.StateSchema(num_uints=7, num_byte_slices=7)
local_schema = transaction.StateSchema(num_uints=1, num_byte_slices=0)
```

When creating a smart contract, there is a limit of 64 key-value pairs that can be used by the contract for global storage and 16 key-value pairs that can be used for local storage.

Comment: https://developer.algorand.org/docs/get-details/dapps/smart-contracts/apps/#creating-the-smart-contract

Comment: @Frank, I added more information regards to the limit.